# How can I exclude a field in "query" of Collection.find(query, projection)

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have an Mongo query

```
var query = {
   age: 20,
   gender: 'male'
}
Students.find(query);
```

Now I want to exclude the field "gender" in query, means that it should return all student with age 20 and doesn't care about the gender. Do I have to create a new query object without "gender"? Can I change the value of "gender" to something like

```
var query = {
   age: 20,
   gender: "all_value"
}
```

to ignore the gender?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just change your query to var `query = { age: 20 }`

Comment: @felix You misunderstand the question. He's asking how to remove the field `gender` from the result set, not how to filter based upon it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
genderList = ['m']
// genderList = ['m', 'f', 'a', 'b', ....]
var query = {
   age: 20,
   gender: {$in: genderList}
}
Students.find(query);
```

Turn gender into list and if it's not specified use the full list of all allowed options.

Or when gender is not specified, set it to `{$exists: true}`

```
var query = {
   age: 20,
   gender: {$exists: true}
}
Students.find(query);
```